# Django python 3 or 2?

Tags: python, django

I'm following the tutorial on Django provided here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ .

All of the python calls in the command line in the tutorial look like this:

```
python <something> <maybe something else>
```

Does this mean that this particular tutorial of Django rests on Python2?

Answer (score 2):

No, its not for specific version. But you can see in doc that the document is for specific version `"This tutorial is written for Django 1.11 and Python 3.4 or later."`. But it not means that use can use only python 3.4 or later,

Answer (score 1):

Django has documentation on [what versions of the framework you can use with which version of Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support). For Django 1.11, you can use Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6.

The use of `python` in the docs as opposed to `python3` doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 1):

The document cleary says that it has been written for python 3.4 or later.
From the django tutorial link

> This tutorial is written for Django 1.11 and Python 3.4 or later. If the Django version doesn’t match, you can refer to the tutorial for your version of Django by using the version switcher at the bottom right corner of this page, or update Django to the newest version. If you are still using Python 2.7, you will need to adjust the code samples slightly, as described in comments.

Further to answer your confusion regarding

> python `<something`> `<maybe something else>`

here **python** means you are invoking the python interpreter.For eg you can do

```
$ python -m django --version
```

where you are invoking the python interpreter (be it any version of python) and checking the version of django.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running `python --version` to check your python version.
This version is used when you use python for Django.
In Ubuntu: `python` corresponds to the default python installation(Python 2.7) and hence you have to mention `python3` to use python3 for Django.

Since Django offers compatibility for both python versions, feel free to use any installation.

Hope it helps.